# unable to pick files like pdf,doc,ppt in MARSHAMALLOW file chooser

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am uploading files like pdf,ppt,doc etc to server using from my android app but in marshmallow when file chooser opens and i browse my Sdcard or internal storage there are two problmes :
  1. it shows all files like images,videos and documents etc which i cannot pick but i used intent type as application/pdf; appkication/ppt etc.,so it should let me pick those files.
  2. secondly when i use external file manager like ES file explorer etc it then show all files like images,videos,documents,apks and this time it lets me choose any type of file
  **here is my code for file chooser**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("application/pdf;application/docx;application/xlsx;application/pptx;application/pptx;application/txt");
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
```

**i am using marshmallow and i think it happens only in marshmallow as i dont have other devices earby to test this code on so help me here Thanks**

i tried it like this

```
intent.setType("application/pdf|application/docx|application/xlsx|application/pptx|application/txt");
```

but it didnt let me chose any file  but if i use only one MIME type like pdf or docx then it works and let me pick pdf or docx and i searched across internet and found this way to use multiple MIME type that is by using | instead of ; and for most of users it works fine but dont for me.

Comment: `setType()` does not take a semicolon-delimited list of types. It takes a *single* MIME type.

Comment: okay but if i want to pick all types of documents like doc,pdf,ppt,xls etc then how should i do it?> @commonsWare

Comment: i tried it like this  
    'intent.setType("application/pdf|application/docx|application/xlsx|application/pptx|application/txt");'

but it didnt let me chose any file  but if i use only one MIME type like pdf or docx then it works and let me pick pdf or docx and i searched across internet and found this way to use multiple MIME type that is by using | instead of ; and for most of users it works fine but dont for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setType()` does not take a pipe-delimited list of types, or a semicolon-delimited list of types. It takes a *single* MIME type.

On API Level 19+ devices, you are welcome to [add `EXTRA_MIME_TYPES`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_MIME_TYPES) to your `Intent` (a `String[]` of additional MIME types). In theory, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` implementations should honor this. In practice, I expect that few would. `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` may be more reliable, in that Android implements that itself, whereas `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` relies upon app developer implementations.

Since your `Intent` is for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` (i.e., you are requesting content), you can use `application/*`, though this will get you some file types that you cannot support.

Otherwise, only ask for one MIME type at a time.

Comment: yes that is what i did . I used 'application/*'
 but yes it is giving me a lot other types of application including apk etc .
But as you said that i can use a String[] of extra mime types in 19+ Api and as i have marshmallow so that will work ?