# Pick Image or video or audio file from gallery

Tags: android, android-intent

I have developed Android application. I need to pick image or audio or video from gallery. I used intent.setType("image/*,video/*,audio/*");. But no solution. it only accepted image. Not getting video or audio.

```
 Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*,audio/*,video/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 0);
```

---

```
        btn_browser_id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*,audio/*,video/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 0);
            }
        });


         @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                Uri selectedMediaUri = data.getData();

                if (selectedMediaUri.toString().contains("image")) {
                   // Log.d(logmessage,"Entered into the image************************* "+selectedMediaUri);
                    //handle image
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    file_type="Image";
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedMediaUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    assert cursor != null;
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    uploadfile.setText(mediaPath);
                    fileupload(mediaPath);
                    //imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaPath));
                    cursor.close();


                } else  if (selectedMediaUri.toString().contains("video")) {
                    //handle video
                    Log.d(logmessage,"Entered into the Video************************* "+selectedMediaUri);
                    file_type="Video";
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedMediaUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    assert cursor != null;
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

                    mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    uploadfile.setText(mediaPath);
                    fileupload(mediaPath);
                    // Set the Video Thumb in ImageView Previewing the Media
                    //imgView.setImageBitmap(getThumbnailPathForLocalFile(MainActivity.this, selectedMediaUri));
                    cursor.close();

                } else  if (selectedMediaUri.toString().contains("audio")) {
                    //handle video
                    Log.d(logmessage,"Entered into the Video************************* "+selectedMediaUri);
                    file_type="Audio";
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedMediaUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    assert cursor != null;
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

                    mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    uploadfile.setText(mediaPath);
                    fileupload(mediaPath);
                    // Set the Video Thumb in ImageView Previewing the Media
                    //imgView.setImageBitmap(getThumbnailPathForLocalFile(MainActivity.this, selectedMediaUri));
                    cursor.close();

                }


            }  else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image/Video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37048341/115145

Comment: Thank you for replying. I open above link but I can't understand. Can you explain please!!!!

Comment: If you do not understand parts of that answer, you need to explain **in detail** what you do not understand.

Comment: I kept code like this : galleryIntent.setType("application/image|application/audio|application/video");   but it crashes.

Comment: The first words of [my answer that I linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37048341/115145) are: "`setType()` does **not** take a pipe-delimited list of types" (emphasis added).

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare I updated my Question. Please See once sir.

Comment: Once again, quoting my answer, "`setType()` does not take a pipe-delimited list of types, or a semicolon-delimited list of types. It takes a single MIME type."